# Revit 2017 API: How to get the currently active view and its graphic overrides

Tags: c#, revit

I am fairly new to Revit API programming and have been wondering how to get the currently active view.
I get a null exception as indicated in the code. What's going wrong here?
My attempt as follows:

```cs
namespace GetActiveView
{
    [TransactionAttribute(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public sealed partial class Class1 : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            //get current view
            var doc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document; //TODO null exception
            Autodesk.Revit.DB.View view = doc.ActiveView;
            ElementId viewID = view.Id;

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you mean `NullReferenceException`? Please provide a stacktrace as well to be able to spot which line of code throws that exception.

Comment: thank you for your comment! Its a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Revit API.

You reference `commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument` without checking for `null`.

When you start up Revit initially with no active document, that property will have a null value.

I would suggest that you get your feet wet by working through the standard [getting started with the Revit API material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) before diving in any further.

That will answer this question and many more, as well as giving you a good founding in the basic fundamentals before trying to go further.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing that out and directing me to some resources.